# how to maintain folder hierarchy in exchnage web service when exporting mails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, exchangewebservices

I am exporting all the e-mails from folder and sub-folder of exchange server, i am able to get all the folder and its mails using the link, (answer ofono2012)

[How To Get all ITEMS from Folders and Sub-folders of PublicFolders Using EWS Managed API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877629/how-to-get-all-items-from-folders-and-sub-folders-of-publicfolders-using-ews-man)

but i am not able to get, which folder was whose sub-folder, means not able to get folder hierarchy

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do a separate FindFolder operation to get the folder hierarchy:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633627(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633627%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Make sure to include `view.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;` and do

```
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);
view.PropertySet.Add(FolderSchema.ParentFolderId);
```

to get the full hierarchy of relationships.  You should then be able to match the ParentFolderId from the items to the folder ids.

Comment: hello rickh, can you tell me where i should put these code given by you,my code is same as the above answer url, for folder and sub-folders

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877629/how-to-get-all-items-from-folders-and-sub-folders-of-publicfolders-using-ews-man

answer i have used is of user:ono2012