# How to list all folders and files in those folders using Exchange Web Services Managed API?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I just discovered the Exchanged Web Services Managed API and I've been playing around with it to try and gain an understanding because I believe it may provide a solution to an issue I've been working on.

**Background**

I've read a lot of the documentation and have a general sense of things. In particular, I set up something very similar to this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877629/how-to-get-all-items-from-folders-and-sub-folders-of-publicfolders-using-ews-man).

However, I want to display a folder, then display all of the related EmailMessage items after the folder, and so on and so forth through all folders/sub-folders. The code I've written so far, will list a folder, but it will list all of the emails that I returned instead of just those emails related to the folder. I'm searching for unread items just to keep the list small for the time-being.

**Code**

```
private static void GetAllItems(ExchangeService service)
    {
        List<Folder> lstFolderIds = new List<Folder>();

        // Fill list with all public folders and sub-folders
        GetAllFolders(service, lstFolderIds);

        List<EmailMessage> emails = new List<EmailMessage>();

        foreach(Folder folder in lstFolderIds)
        {
            SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
            ItemView view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
            view.PropertySet = PropertySet.IdOnly;

            FindItemsResults<Item> searchResults = service.FindItems(folder.Id, sf, view);

            if (searchResults.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in searchResults.Items)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (item is EmailMessage)
                        {
                            emails.Add((EmailMessage)item);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
                        Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", ex.Source);
                        Console.WriteLine("HResult: {0}", ex.HResult);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        PropertySet properties = (BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        service.LoadPropertiesForItems(emails, properties);

        foreach (Folder folder in lstFolderIds)
        {
            object folderName;
            object displayName;
            object childFolderCount;
            object unreadCount;
            object totalCount;

            folderName = folder.TryGetProperty(FolderSchema.ParentFolderId, out folderName) ? folder.ParentFolderId.FolderName.Value.ToString() : "N/A";
            displayName = folder.TryGetProperty(FolderSchema.DisplayName, out displayName) ? folder.DisplayName.ToString() : "N/A";
            childFolderCount = folder.TryGetProperty(FolderSchema.ChildFolderCount, out childFolderCount) ? folder.ChildFolderCount.ToString() : "N/A";
            unreadCount = folder.TryGetProperty(FolderSchema.UnreadCount, out unreadCount) ? folder.UnreadCount.ToString() : "N/A";
            totalCount = folder.TryGetProperty(FolderSchema.TotalCount, out totalCount) ? folder.TotalCount.ToString() : "N/A";

            Console.WriteLine("Parent Folder: {0}", folderName);
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Display Name: {0}", displayName);
            Console.WriteLine("Child Folder Count: {0}", childFolderCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Unread Count: {0}", unreadCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Total Count: {0}", totalCount);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
            foreach (EmailMessage email in emails)
            {
                object parentFolderName;
                object subject;
                object retentionDate;

                parentFolderName = email.TryGetProperty(EmailMessageSchema.ParentFolderId, out parentFolderName) ? email.ParentFolderId.FolderName.Value.ToString() : "N/A";
                subject = email.TryGetProperty(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, out subject) ? email.Subject.ToString() : "N/A";
                retentionDate = email.TryGetProperty(EmailMessageSchema.RetentionDate, out retentionDate) ? retentionDate.ToString() : "N/A";

                Console.WriteLine("\tParent Folder Name: {0}", parentFolderName);
                Console.WriteLine("\tSubject: {0}", subject);
                Console.WriteLine("\tRetention Date: {0}", retentionDate);
                //}                    
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Press or select Enter...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Part of the problem is that I can't figure out how to get the folder name for the folder or the parent folder name for the EmailMessage. I can get the folder ID for the folder and the parent folder ID for the EmailMessage, but they are identical for all items that are returned, so it must not be right.

I read in this [LINK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c9fe596d-1852-44f2-8a4f-fac904291d6b/ews-2007-how-find-which-known-folder-an-emailmessageparentfolderid-resides-in?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) that I may need to carry out an additional bind to relate the folders with the EmailMessage items, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

**Expected Output**

```
Parent Folder: 
Folder Display Name: Inbox
Child Folder Count: 1
Folder Unread Count: 2
Folder Total Count: 51
---------------------------------------------------------
    Parent Folder Name: Inbox
    Subject: New Coversheets for TPS Reports
    Retention Date: 10/31/2017 11:59:59 PM

    Parent Folder Name: Inbox
    Subject: Have you seen my stapler?
    Retention Date: 07/31/2017 11:59:59 PM

Parent Folder: 
Folder Display Name: Sent Items
Child Folder Count: 0
Folder Unread Count: 0
Folder Total Count: 27
---------------------------------------------------------
    No Un-Read Items
```

**Questions**

1. How do I list the folder hierarchy with related EmailMessages that match my search condition?
2. Is the FolderId/ParentFolderId that I'm currently obtaining the Id for the MsgFolderRoot or is there any way to tell?
3. How do I obtain the Folder.FolderId.FolderName.Value and the EmailMessage.ParentFolderId.FolderName.Value?
4. If binding is necessary for #2, does anyone have an example or link they would share that illustrates the action?

**Update(s)**

1. Added a section for expected output before questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After perusing the object browser, I discovered that the use of the `FolderName` property is mutually exclusive from the `FolderId` property, which explained why my `parentFolderId.FolderName.Value` code was always returning null.

I reorganized my code to build the hierarchy and used the `ParentFolderId` property for an `EmailMessage` to bind to the parent folder, which allowed me to obtain the parent folder's `DisplayName` property.

Comment: It would be nice if you could share some of the code from your solution in this answer please.

Comment: @Caltor - All the code I used in my solution is in the original post with two changes. The line `PropertySet properties = (BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);` was changed to `PropertySet properties = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.ParentFolderId);`. And the line that starts with `parentFolderName = email.TryGetProperty(EmailMessageSchema.ParentFolderId, out parentFolderName)` was changed to `parentFolderId = email.TryGetProperty(EmailMessageSchema.ParentFolderId, out parentFolderId)`.