# SSIS Script Task to extract file from mailbox subfolder

Tags: ssis

I want to extract a file from a mailbox sub-folder. The below works for the inbox but how do I tell it to go to a sub-folder down the tree from the inbox.

```
//Bind the Inbox folder to the service object
Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Andy,
I think what you're asking is an EWS-specific question on how you might traverse folders.  ono2012 shared some starter code on: [How to Get All ITEMS from Folders and Sub-folders of PublicFolders Using EWS Managed API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877629/how-to-get-all-items-from-folders-and-sub-folders-of-publicfolders-using-ews-man)

I think it will be helpful to you.